# clang complete issue for cross compiled code (sizes of types are different)

Tags: vim, cross-platform, clang, sizeof, powerpc

I ran into an issue with the *clang complete* plugin in vim. The development system is Linux/i86_64, but the codebase is for PowerPC/32. The problem is that clang and the cross compiler disagree about the sizes of types. On PowerPC, `sizeof long` is 4, while on i86_64 it is 8.

This causes a compile-time-assert to fail that checks the size of a certain struct. As a consequence, clang complete only says `-- User defined comletion (^U^N^P)` and does nothing else. If I remove the compile-time-assert, everything works fine.

Is there a way to teach clang that it is not checking native code, but cross compiled code where the sizes of types are different? I.e. can I tell clang what it shall assume about the size of native types like `int` and `long`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my surprise, even the i86_64 clang supports the option

```
 -target powerpc
```

for which the sizes of types have the correct type. I have added this line to my `.clang_complete` and it did the trick.